# in Android Studio the Button in ListView does not work

Tags: android, listview

I'm creating a shopping list similar to listonic app, but I'm stuck in listView, the button inside my listView does not read clicks but OnItemClickListener is working well. the objective is the user can save multiple shopping list for example grocery list, self-care list, etc. I have searched everywhere but did not find something that works.

here is the activity for the shopping list

```
private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    private FloatingActionButton addList;
    private ListView listView;
    private TextView nList_name;

    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_lists);

        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        addList = findViewById(R.id.add_list);

        loadTaskList();

        addList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                add_item();
            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(MyListsActivity.this, "list num "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
    {
        private final int layout;

        public MyListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<String> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            layout = resource;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            final int pos = position;

            if (convertView == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.thumbnail = convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_thumbnail);
                viewHolder.title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text);
                viewHolder.button = convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_btn);
            }
            else
            {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            viewHolder.title.setText(getItem(position));
            viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(MyListsActivity.this, "btn at row "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            return convertView;
        }

    }

    public static class ViewHolder
    {
        ImageView thumbnail;
        TextView title;
        Button button;
    }

    private void add_item()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyListsActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add new list");

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(MyListsActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.shop_list_dialog_item, null, false);
        builder.setView(v);
        TextInputEditText nList_name_edit_txt = v.findViewById(R.id.list_name_edit_txt);
        TextInputLayout nList_name_layout = v.findViewById(R.id.list_name_layout);
        builder.setPositiveButton("CREATE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i){}
        }).setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {dialogInterface.cancel();}
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                String task = String.valueOf(nList_name_edit_txt.getText()).trim();
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(nList_name_edit_txt.getText()))
                {
                    dbHelper.insertNewTask(task);
                    loadTaskList();
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
                else{nList_name_layout.setError("Name your list");}

            }
        });

    }
    private void loadTaskList() {
        ArrayList<String> taskList = dbHelper.getTaskList();
        if(mAdapter==null){
            mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_wrapper_item, R.id.list_item_text, taskList);
            listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
        else{
            mAdapter.clear();
            mAdapter.addAll(taskList);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

this is the xml for the shopping list activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyListsActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

    </ListView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is the layout for the adapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_image_24" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:textColor="@color/youtube"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/list_item_thumbnail"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/list_item_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Do you mean that `viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener...` does not get called? (position should be final because it's called from inner class)

Comment: Where are creating `MyListAdapter` object? Your code does not seem to use `MyListAdapter`

Comment: @MatiasLappalainen yeah ` viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener... ` it's not called and I tried assigning position to final but the button still does not get called but I will fix that. about my list adapter `MyListAdapter` i don't really know how to use it correctly, I tried putting `MyListAdapter` inside `onCreate()` but the lists were not showing up, but after removing it the lists are showing up but the buttons inside the lists do not get called.

Comment: At the moment you are not using `MyListAdapter` because of that the button does nothing. I advice you to look into [arrayAdapters](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter) or look up a tutorial. At the moment you are using arrayAdapter classes constructor to create ArrayAdapter. This works in some cases but here when you want to add custom features like `OnClickListeners` you want to create your own CustomAdapter like you have done. So you are doing the right thing but not using it.

Comment: thank you so much @MatiasLappalainen I will look into the documentation and try to understand the `arrayAdapters`. I followed 2 or 3 tutorials on how to make this `Listview` . can you give me any tips on how to use the adapter that I have? cause when I use it the items of the list dissapear. thanks again for your comments

Comment: What "cause when I use it the items of the list dissapear" means? I added answer. Does it work? I tested `MyListAdapter` and it works as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MyListAdapter` works as it should except `int position` should be `final int position` because `button` calls it from inner class.

The problem is that you are not using `MyListAdapter`. So change

```
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_wrapper_item, R.id.list_item_text, taskList);
```

To

```
mAdapter = new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_wrapper_item, taskList);
```